# Ignite event listener registration error

Tags: events, listener, ignite

I am trying to implement a remote listener on Apache ignite, but for some reason the registration seems to be failing, use the following code.

```
IgniteMessaging message = ignite.message(ignite.cluster());
message.remoteListen("topic1", new IgniteBiPredicate<UUID, String>() {

    @Override
    public boolean apply(UUID e1, String e2) {
        System.out.println("message received" + e2);
        return true;
    }
    });
```

But I get the following error during registration.

```js
Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to marshal custom event: StartRoutineDiscoveryMessage [startReqData=StartRequestData [prjPred=AlwaysTruePredicate [], clsName=null, depInfo=null, hnd=GridMessageListenHandler [pred=independent.messaging.Receiver$1@e24ddd0, clsName=null, depInfo=null, depEnabled=false], bufSize=1, interval=0, autoUnsubscribe=false], keepBinary=false, routineId=13f09f06-4ebe-4cc8-9671-54162472df15]
 at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendCustomEvent(ServerImpl.java:773)
 at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.sendCustomEvent(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:453)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.sendCustomEvent(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2090)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.startRoutine(GridContinuousProcessor.java:748)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteMessagingImpl.remoteListen(IgniteMessagingImpl.java:212)
 at independent.messaging.Receiver.listenForMessages(Receiver.java:71)
 at independent.messaging.Receiver.main(Receiver.java:55)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to serialize object: StartRoutineDiscoveryMessage [startReqData=StartRequestData [prjPred=AlwaysTruePredicate [], clsName=null, depInfo=null, hnd=GridMessageListenHandler [pred=independent.messaging.Receiver$1@e24ddd0, clsName=null, depInfo=null, depEnabled=false], bufSize=1, interval=0, autoUnsubscribe=false], keepBinary=false, routineId=13f09f06-4ebe-4cc8-9671-54162472df15]
 at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.marshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:85)
 at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.marshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:70)
 at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.marshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:99)
 at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.marshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:58)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.marshal(IgniteUtils.java:9815)
 at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendCustomEvent(ServerImpl.java:769)
 ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: independent.messaging.Receiver
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.GridMessageListenHandler.writeExternal(GridMessageListenHandler.java:244)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1459)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1430)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.StartRequestData.writeExternal(StartRequestData.java:241)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1459)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1430)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
 at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.marshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:80)
 ... 11 more
```

What could be the possible reason for this error?

Answer (score 4):

Your IgniteBiPredicate will be serialized and sent to the other nodes, so, in your case, as this class is anonymous, outer class will be serialized too.

I would recommend creating private static class for predicate with this implementation and creating instance of it as an argument for remoteListen method

Comment: This answer helped alot - thank you!
I wonder why the documentation still shows code similar to the example above.
[link](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/events/listening-to-events#listening-to-remote-events)